# Passing a structure through a FIFO

Tags: c

I have written a simple code where one process is passing a structure to another process, the parent process is writing the data, but child process is not able to access it. I have used `fork()` system call to create two processes. But i have problem here the parent process i called twice and child process is also called twice when i run the program. Can any one let me know what mistake i am doing.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN    100
#define FIFO_NAME "my_fifo"

typedef struct student_info  {
char *name;
int age;
char *sex;
}student;

int w_byte_parent = 0, r_byte_parent = 0;
int w_byte_child = 0, r_byte_child = 0;

void do_child() {
  int fifo;
  char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
  int i = 0;
  student child;

  printf("Child opening FIFO \n");
  if( (fifo = open(FIFO_NAME, O_RDWR)) < 0 )   {
    perror("open in child failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  printf("Child  reading  from FIFO \n");
  r_byte_child = read(fifo, child, sizeof(student));
  if(r_byte_child < 0)
    printf("Read failed by child process\n");
  printf("%d Bytes read by child process\n", r_byte_child);
  }

 int main(int argc, char **argv)  {
 int fifo;
 char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
 int ch = 0, i = 0;

 /*
 ** Create a FIFO
 */
 /* Parent creating FIFO */
if( (mkfifo(FIFO_NAME, 0666)) < 0)  {
    if( errno != EEXIST ) {
        perror( "mkfifo" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
/*
 ** Create other process 
 */

switch(fork())  {
    case -1:
        perror("fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    case 0: /* Child Process */
        do_child();
        break;
    default:/* Parent Process */
        break;
}
/* Pass a structure to FIFO */
student *info;
info = (student *)malloc( sizeof (student)) ;
info->name = (char *)calloc(sizeof(char), 10);
strcpy(info->name, "jack");
info->age = 27;
info->sex = (char *)calloc(sizeof(char), 10);
strcpy(info->sex , "Male");

/* Parent Opening FIFO */
printf("parent opening FIFO \n");
if( (fifo = open(FIFO_NAME,  O_RDWR)) < 0 )   {
    perror("open in parent failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/*
 ** Write some thing into FIFO so child can read it
 */
printf("parent writing to FIFO \n");
w_byte_parent = write( fifo, info, sizeof(struct student_info));
if(w_byte_parent < 0)
    printf("Nothing was written to FIFO by parent\n");
printf("Wrote %d bytes to FIFO\n",w_byte_parent);
}
```

Comment: Both the parent and child drop out of the switch(fork()). Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with the basics.  Compiling your code with GCC with the `-Wall` option:

```
$ gcc fifo.c -o fifo -Wall
fifo.c: In function ‘do_child’:
fifo.c:33: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘read’
fifo.c:24: warning: unused variable ‘i’
fifo.c:23: warning: unused variable ‘buffer’
fifo.c: In function ‘main’:
fifo.c:48: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mkfifo’
fifo.c:58: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fork’
fifo.c:88: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘write’
fifo.c:42: warning: unused variable ‘i’
fifo.c:42: warning: unused variable ‘ch’
fifo.c:41: warning: unused variable ‘buffer’
fifo.c:92: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Ignoring all of the unused variables problems, you need to include `<unistd.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>` to get proper declarations of `read`, `mkfifo`, `fork`, and `write`.  Compiling again:

```
$ gcc fifo.c -o fifo -Wall -Wno-unused
fifo.c: In function ‘do_child’:
fifo.c:35: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘read’
fifo.c: In function ‘main’:
fifo.c:94: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

You're passing a `student` instance as parameter 2 to `read`, but it expects a `void*` pointer.  You need to pass the *address* of the `student` instance as `&child`.  Also, it would be good to explicitly return a value form `main()`, although that's not strictly necessary, since failing to return a value form `main()` implicitly returns 0 (but *only* for the `main()` function).

But even with those errors corrected, you still see the output of the parent process twice.  Why?  Because both the parent and the child processes are executing the code block below the switch statement.  The child process calls the `do_child()` function and never exits, so it returns and continues executing.

The simple fix to that is make sure to exit the child process, either at the end of `do_child()`, or immediately after the call returns, e.g.

Comment: You're halfway there, I think.  The next thing the OP will want to know is how to convey the dynamically allocated values pointed to by struct members.

Comment: The declaration of `open()` is in `<fcntl.h>` — weird, but so.

Comment: @pilcrow: Yes, that's true.  In this case, since the child process was `fork`ed from the parent with `exec`ing anything, and since the data structure wasn't modified, it's ok to slurp pointers across the FIFO and have them be usable in the receiving process.  But as soon as one of the processes modifies the data, the copy-on-write kicks in, and the processes are no longer sharing the memory (unless they explicitly set up a shared memory region beforehand), and you need to use a proper serialization mechanism.

Comment: I may have misread `main()`, but it looks like all relevant `[cm]alloc` calls are done post-`fork()`.

Comment: @pilcrow: Oh, you're right, I didn't read it carefully enough.